# BigQuery - SESSION_USER() do not display the current user email ( Google data Studio)

Tags: google-bigquery, looker-studio

This is SQL view which I'm using ( Standard SQL)

```
SELECT
  SESSION_USER() AS USER
```

As well I have tested Legacy one

```
SELECT
  CURRENT_USER() AS USER
```

In both circumstances, it displays my name when I run view through Data Studio, any suggestions that it will display email based on who opens this Data Studio report?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I **think** if your connection to the data-set uses you credentials then it will bring back your email.

If you change the report data-set in data studio from owner credential to viewer credential it should bring the email of the person viewing the report. However, they will need to have access to the data-set to see any data.